# Getting unexpected error when adding columns to a list or a Doc Library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: iis, sharepoint-2010

I am getting an unexpected error (see below) when I try to add a column to a list.

> Error  An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 6efebddc-675d-43fd-8754-43cea59908b7
>
> Date and Time: 08/24/2011 12:06:16 PM

From the SharePoint log I have found the below details.

06:16.8 w3wp.exe (0x01A8)  0x1080  SharePoint Foundation  Runtime  tkau  Unexpected  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: s    at System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ManageFieldPage.ProcessList()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ManageFieldPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 6efebddc-675d-43fd-8754-43cea59908b7

I have two front-end Web servers, two databases and one application server.
Does it have anything to do with [alternate access mappings](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/fromthefield/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=8) (AAM) as it's accessible through the Internet using HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out more information about the error you need to look in the SharePoint log for the errors/warnings associated with the Correlation ID.  Try using a tool like ULSViewer found here http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3308.

1. Start ULSViewer and have it start to monitor the SharePoint Log file.
2. Once ULSViewer is populating with log entries perform the activity that is causing the error.
3. Pause ULSViewer and then filter by the Correlation ID.  This will give you a better idea of what is failing and possibly why.

Comment: I managed to get the error as posted above "Value cannot be null" I believe that its all about AAM as in the error below: 
Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://mousharaka.nyu.edu:80/_...
it seems that the application is trying to get Content types from http url but fails because it is mapped to HTTPS. 
any idea?

Comment: Is this an fresh 2010 install or was it upgraded from MOSS2007?

Answer (score 0):

It was an AAM issue. My host name was not mapped to HTTPS, and after mapping it to HTTPS the error is gone,

```
http://myhostname -> https://myhostname
```